# JavaScript IF ELSE statement in string line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript like this:

```
var myParam = 1;
var myVar = 'Lorem ipsum dolor [placeholder] amet';
```

I need to check, if `myParam` will be `1` then put inline of `myVar` - `one` else put there `two`. Something like this:

```
var myParam = 1;
var myVar = 'Lorem ipsum dolor '+ if (myParam == 1) return 'one' else return 'two' +' amet';
```

How to put `IF/ELSE` statement inside sting?

Comment: Please consider using `===` instead of `==`. If you know the type (Number or String) you can safely use `===`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I want to check if object has propery `value` like this:

`myVar = 'some text '+ (typeof Obj.value != 'undefined' ? Obj.value : 'N/A') +' another text';`

Which of these should I use `!=` or `!==`  ??

Comment: `typeof` will always return a string, and `'undefined'` is a string, so use `!==`. I have always claimed that there is never a valid reason to use `==` (or `!=`), if you know of one I'd love to hear about it :)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen and what is the difference? is there any matter of performance?

Comment: Yes, but I don't believe performance is the main reason, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: I got now. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a ternary expression:

```
var myVar = 'Lorem ipsum dolor ' + (myParam == 1 ? 'one' : 'two') +' amet';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**ternary operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), *where `?:` operator can be used as a shortcut for an `if...else` statement.*

> **Syntax:** test ? expression1 : expression2

like

```
(myParam == 1) ?'one' : 'two'
```

Answer (score 0):

`(myParam == 1) ? true : false;`

You might want to think about `===` - or myParam could be 1, or "1", to use a basic example.

Answer (score -1):

Using Ternary operator:

```
<condition> ? true: false

'Lorem ipsum dolor '+ ((myParam == 1) ? 'one' : 'two') +' amet';
```